# clean RecyclerView after tap to button Back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onbackpressed

I have RecyclerView that is filled with a list of items received from the server response.

First, the user enters a log / password and selects a specific content, such as: 1 content.

After login the user go to the activity with has RecyclerView, where there are fields of content 1.

When user click on the Back button he goes back to the main activity of registration and selects the already content 2. After clicking the Login button, again goes to RecyclerView, but for some reason it has fields from the content 1 and fields content 2 Add to end of list.

I use this methods :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
    unswerFromMain.clear();
    recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain);
}
```

This is in Adapter :

```
public void updateAdapter (ArrayList<Unswer> updateUnswer){

    getUnswer.clear();
    getUnswer.addAll(updateUnswer);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

All this method didn`t work.

Comment: you must clear adapter and then use adapter.notifydatasetchange and in last line user super.onBackPressed();

Comment: but I did it...

Comment: recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I put it, didn`t help (( I put empty ArrayList, I put clear ArrayList - after i call method  updateAdapter , with contain notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are calling `onBackPressed()` before you do anything else. This means those other lines never run. Try swapping it around:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
    unswerFromMain.clear();
    recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is didn`t help(

Comment: what if after `recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain)` you call `recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: I edit my topic, where I show method updateAdapter. In this method I use  notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Set an empty array into your adapter and notify

```
adapter.setItems(new ArrayList<MyPOJO>);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

EDIT

You should call super.onBackpressed for the last. Like this

```
@Override
```

public void onBackPressed() {

```
recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
recyclerView.removeAllViews();
unswerFromMain.clear();
recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain);
super.onBackPressed();
```

}

Comment: I edit my topic and add method, which i call to update my adapter by the empty Array. It`s didn`t help(

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug.

The problem was not to clean the adapter, it was not cleansed ArrayList which was from the main activity. This ArrayList contains a field content 1 and when I was at activity with RecyclerView and pressed the Back button that returns to the main activity already filled ArrayList data content 1. Then I chose the content 2 and the data on it just added to the end of the ArrayList.

I completely removed all methods onBackPressed (), except super.onBackPressed (); and everything was working fine. Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried with above answer are not work for me.

So I have handle RecyclerView with hide and show.

**recyclerview.setVisiblity(View.GONE);**

recyclerview.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);

and my logic is,

first initialize one int value globally like, **int clicked = 0;**

BackPress event use that below code:

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    if(recycler_view!=null){
        if(clicked==0){
            recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            clicked =1;
        }else{
            finishAffinity();
        }
    }else {
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

**When you show(recyclerview.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);) recyclerview in activity that time set Clicked =0**

So, easy way to show and hide recyclerview as well as backpress also handled.